# Why doesn't routerLink navigate to page after user once logs out?

Tags: angular, routes, routerlink, navigateurl

I have links as *"Register"* on login page & *"Login"* on register page. I used the code below to navigate:

```
<p>Not a member? <a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a></p>
```

and

```
<p>Already have an account? <a routerLink="/login">Login</a></p>
```

Code works perfectly fine if the user is not already logged in. User can navigate to both pages back and forth. **But once the user is logged in, and logs out it cannot navigate to Register page anymore (without refreshing the page)**. The route changes to /register but the page is not loaded.

I have `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` on app.component.html & also tried some other solutions from previous questions but nothing's working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a routerLink="/register">Register</a>
```

That might fix it.

Also try checking your console logs for errors. An error in the console can stop the router from working.

However, the most likely reason is that a guard is blocking it. Check your guard logic (this happened to me recently).

Comment: This didnt work either: <a routerLink="/register">Register</a>, no errors on console log.    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: {title: 'Login'}},
 { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: { title: 'Register' } }, I have also removed the guards from route configurations